# Map is not initialized, with Rviz and Gazebo simulation, ROS2

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I have been following the Turtlebot3 tutorial with ROS2 Dashing (http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2/#ros2) which works fine for all the steps.
Now, i want to try out simulation in gazebo and navigation2 with a simple robot i have built on my own. As a starter i have been using the turtlebot files, the only thing i have changed is the design of the robot (inside the model and urdf files). The sensors etc. is kept the same. I also use the map and world for turtlebot3.
I want to perform the simulation part in the tutorial.
First I run the command:

```
 ros2 launch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_world.launch.py
```

which correctly visualize the robot and world in Gazebo.
Then I run

```
ros2 launch turtlebot3_navigation2 navigation2.launch.py use_sim_time:=True map:=$HOME/map.yaml
```

RviZ opens with the correct map, but a lot of errors occur both in Rviz and in the terminalwindow:

[rviz2-9] [ERROR] [rviz2]: "map" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
[amcl-3] [INFO] [amcl_rclcpp_node]: [signalFailure] Drop message: frame 'base_scan' at time 21.617 for reason(0)

When I used the turtlebot model, this errors also occurred, but they where removed when I set the initial pose for the robot.
Now, when I try to set the initial pose, the command line tells that amcl has received an initial pose and set it:

[amcl-3] [INFO] [amcl]: initialPoseReceived
[amcl-3] [INFO] [amcl]: Setting pose (0.000000): 1.445 0.511 -2.742
[amcl-3] [INFO] [amcl]: Received a 384 X 384 map @ 0.050 m/pix
[amcl-3] [INFO] [amcl]: Setting pose (0.000000): 1.445 0.511 -2.742

But the errors in rviz are still there and the command window keeps printing the same errors as before.

The error in Rviz are Global Status: Error, Fixed Frame:Frame [map] does not exist.

I assume it is the transform between the map and gazebo/odom(?) which is missing, but I tought it would be fine when I set the initial pose for the robot.
Does anyone have any suggestions to what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335072/map-is-not-initialized,-with-rviz-and-gazebo-simulation,-ros2/) by [ninamwa](https://answers.ros.org/users/45886/ninamwa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2019-10-10

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image: image description]

Try to have the `Fixed Frame` changed. For example, a `world` frame.

http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/UserGuide#Coordinate_Frames

---

Originally posted by [vaspo](https://answers.ros.org/users/38387/vaspo/) with karma: 61 on 2020-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1